# Server tag not well formed

Tags: c#

I am trying to use Web.Router and I am trying to set it in a hyperlink where some variables need to be binded from a dataTable. Also, this link is a part of a Gridview:-

```
    <a href='<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%# String.Format("$RouteUrl:id={0},title={1}", Eval("ID"), Eval("title") %>" />' target="_blank" style="color:#330000; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold"><%# Eval("title")) %></a>
```

But I get error:  Server Tag not well formed. What's wrong with the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
<a href='<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%# String.Format("$RouteUrl:id={0},title={1}", Eval("ID"), Eval("title") %>" />' target="_blank" style="color:#330000; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold"><%# Eval("title")) %></a>
```

To this

```
<a href='<asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%# String.Format("$RouteUrl:id={0},title={1}", Eval("ID"), Eval("title") %>" />' target="_blank" style="color:#330000; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold"><%# Eval("title")) %></a>
```

You put a double quot instead of single quot